# Sonar rule - Reorder the modifiers for interface default methods

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, rule

I just started using Sonar and I have a project with JDK 8. The only problem I've got so far is:

```
Reorder the modifiers to comply with the Java Language Specification.
```

This is happening for my default methods in interfaces, like

```
default boolean isValid([params here]) { 
  /*method body here*/
}
```

I know that this is really a minor issue, but I don't want to disable any rule, so how do you fix it?

Thank you very much!

p.s. I haven't found anything on Google, I know what this rule means(I have read its description), but I cannot figure out how to deal with default keyword.

**Update**: It looks like a bug, I have reported it here, https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-590
**Update 2**: It seems it's already fixed and it will be available in 2.4 version.

Comment: What version of Sonar are you using? Are you sure it supports Java 8?

Comment: I'm using Sonar 4.3.2 with Java plugin 2.3. I am also running the coverage using the Maven plugin for Sonar, same version, 2.3. So yes, I am sure Java 8 is supported.

Comment: Despite what you say, I suspect you may be dealing with a version that doesn't support Java 8. Otherwise, this would be not only a bug but complete and utter nonsense. There *is* no order of modifiers in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4). They can occur in any order.

Comment: The [JLS sec 8.4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) *recommends* a particular ("customary") order for method modifiers for classes, though violating this is not an error. There are similar clauses for field declarations of classes and interfaces, though curiously not for interface method modifiers. I suppose it could be considered bad style to declare an interface method `strictfp default` instead of `default strictfp`, though this is pretty silly. This is apparently the kind of thing that Sonar checks, though.

Comment: Yes, but I only have the default modifier, so the 8.4.3 sec is not affecting me. But thank you for pointing out, I didn't know about it.

Comment: I answered with the correct ticket, yours was created on the wrong project. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method declaration syntax for interfaces is covered in the [JLS, section 9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4).

Briefly, method modifiers must precede the method header, which includes the method's return type. Your declaration has one method modifier `default` and its return type is `boolean` so there is no other possible arrangement in this declaration other than

```
default boolean isValid(/*parameters*/) { /*body*/ }
```

Therefore I think this must be a bug in Sonar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will accept it as it seems the only logical explanation. I have also reported the bug, see the updated question :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Great, thanks for filing the Sonar bug.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Thanks for your feedback.

You can have a look at the source code of the check : [ModifiersOrderCheck](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/1cb0349490c0fb6e49b8c2164306a55ff6614282/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/ModifiersOrderCheck.java)(link to last commit at time of writing)

And you will see that the `default` modifier is not checked as this rule was not updated since the support of Java 8 in the sonar-java-plugin.

So it is indeed a bug, but it has to be reported on the java plugin project and not on the Mojo's sonar maven plugin. I created the correct ticket:  https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-590 Feel free to vote for it.

Comment: I don't have the rights to submit a bug in the SONARJAVA project. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem ! Better a bad report than no report :)